# Matching almost all cases from multiple columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image: Highlighted row is data I want to compare]I am trying to measure the validity of questionnaire responses in excel. One of my tests is checking whether the person answering it just chose the same response for many questions in a row. I am trying to detect a pattern for 6 questions where the possible responses are 1-6. I am not looking for a case where all the responses are a specific number, but for any case where all 6 responses are the same eg all 5's all 4's etc.
The responses to the questions are located in columns next to each other, ie C, D, E...H and each respondent is in their own row.
Additionally I would like to see the cases where 5 of the 6 responses are the same, because I believe there is some likelihood that a person might just select a single answer differently to make it seem more believable. My guess is if this problem can be solved for 5 out 6 cases, 6 out 6 is more straightforward

I can share my current failure which is using if statements and/or countifs to try and match a=b, b=c and so forth. One article which describes this way is [Compare two columns for matches and differences](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/08/26/excel-compare-two-columns-matches-differences/)

I am open to solutions with vba, as I have used it a bit in the past, but it would have to be fairly step-by-step, I'm coming back to excel after not using it for a while

Cheers

Comment: Could you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1437191/edit) top add sample data? It would make things a lot easier to understand

Comment: I added a picture, I don't think I can upload a file (not that anyone wants to dl random excel files from a person on the internet anyways) :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me suggest a different approach that's simple and scalable to any number of questions by just adjusting the data range.  You framed the question as the number of responses that match.  This solution looks at it from the other direction, the number that don't match.  If there are zero non-matches, it means they are all the same.  If there is one non-match, it means all but one match (your 5 out of 6 case, but one non-match applies to any number of questions).

[image]

The formula in J2 is:

```
=COUNTA(C2:H2)-MAX(FREQUENCY(C2:H2,C2:H2))
```

I wasn't sure how you would want to handle a missing response.  This solution ignores missing responses and treats the actual responses as you describe.  The COUNTA counts the number of actual responses.  If you want to treat a blank as a different answer, you could replace COUNTA with the actual number of questions.

The FREQUENCY function determines the counts of each unique response.  MAX gives you the maximum frequency, which doesn't care which specific response that represents.  Anything less than all the same gives you a result greater than zero.

If you just want to distinguish `0` and `1`, you can wrap this formula with IF tests or CHOOSE.  You can simply hide any result `>1` with a null result (`""`), or display specific text responses for `0` and `1`.

Comment: Thank you, I marked this as accepted because it's scalable and easily flexible. 0 non-matches 1 etc.

Answer (score 1):

A really long If/And/Or statement will do it.

```
=if(Or(And(A1=B1,B1=C1,C1=D1,D1=E1),And(B1=C1,C1=D1,D1=E1,E1=F1).....),"Lots of things in a row match","Not a lot of things in a row match")
```

It gets easier as you go along, since you can copy most of the previous `AND` statement into the next one, then just write the next comparison. For example, for the 3rd `AND` you just need to copy `C1=D1,D1=E1,E1=F1`from the previous `AND`, then add in `F1=G1` at the end. Rinse and repeat.

It gets much easier if you throw the data into an Excel table as well

Comment: This worked, copy & paste was a good suggestion. My only gripe is that this is fairly manual, and if I wanted to do this with 15 variables and +-2 (I do in fact) this solution would be unworkable. I'm thinking of reframing the question to reflect this.

Comment: You can leave the last few "hanging" as a blank - since you have 5 items, and only 4 will be blank at a time, it won't trigger the error. The only issue would be if you could have more blanks than items in a row that you want - at which point you could enter something like "Null Q 23", "Null Q 24"

Answer (score 1):

Another method using `SUMPRODUCT`:

this will check if there are six sequential answers that are the same anywhere in a row between columns `T` and `AI`:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(T2:AC2=U2:AD2),--(U2:AD2=V2:AE2),--(V2:AE2=W2:AF2),--(W2:AF2=X2:AG2),--(X2:AG2=Y2:AH2))>0,"six in a row","")
```

Here is an explanation of [`SUMPRODUCT`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-16753E75-9F68-4874-94AC-4D2145A2FD2E).

Using equalities to generate true (`1`) or false (`0`) results you can then run them through the `SUMPRODUCT`.

Edited: a brief explanation also notice a problem in the formula and fixed it

Comment: This looks interesting, I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the syntax of this, I'm looking it up rn, would you mind explaining a bit what the command is actually doing?